# Load JS scripts synchronously

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm creating a pretty complex application and want all my tens of JavaScript entities definitions  to load on demand. I need to load them just before use and must ensure they've loaded prior to any callings.
Looks like the RequireJS is what i need, but I still have no idea how to use it without callbacks. I'd like to ensure (or wait for) the JS library have been fully loaded before I use it. Yes, I know the syntax of

```
require([<js-file-name>], callback)
```

, but is there any way to implement synchronous loading instead of async? It's not always possible to use callbacks. For example, if you have a loop that populates an array with the items that requires different js file to be loaded then you'll have a wrong order because different scripts loading take differebt time.

Comment: Your loop can be recoded to work properly with asynchronous loading so that is a false assumption you are starting with.  It's just a matter of the correct design to work with async operations in the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you mean everything written in sync can be made in async with no overhead and billions of nested callbacks?

Comment: No, I mean there exists a decent design that would work with async.  You don't have to turn every operation into a synchronous operation in order to solve a looping problem.  You don't show us the code you're really trying to write so it's not possible to make suggestions there.  Instead, you came here with a false assumption and are trying to make everything synchronous to fit into that false assumption.  Writing good, clean, maintainable asynchronous code is something to be learned and mastered.  It is not as easy as writing synchronous code, but is definitely worth learning and using.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, thank you for clarification. I've not been programming much under JS and looks like really need to learn this design approaches. Voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right answer is to unroll your loop into a recursive function. That way you can use the callbacks or promises or whatever async mechanism you like, but still load scripts dynamically (and asynchronously, which - trust me - you want).

Async definitely comes at a price, but think of the alternative: the UI thread grinds to a halt while your scripts are loading. That's not the experience you or anybody else wants.

Of all the languages I'm familiar with, C# has the easiest way to introduce async into existing code patterns, but once you're used to it, JavaScript's not bad. It's not all that difficult to use (say) JQuery promises to handle your async tasks. As I said, you need to use different code patterns, and they're typically not as straightforward as simple loops, but you can usually find a way to do it that's not insanely difficult.

EDIT: If you're coding up your async stuff right, you don't usually need to worry about call stack depth. Just make sure that every recursive call is hanging (in some fashion) off of a JQuery Promise, and your stack will stay just fine. Something like this:

```
function executeTasks (tasks) {
    var i = 0;
    var executeTask = function (task) {
        $.getScript(task.script).done(function () {
            task.method();
            if (++i <= tasks.length) {
                executeTask(task[i]);
            }
        });
    }
    executeTask(tasks[i]);
}
```

Comment: So a call stack of say 200 items is normal for JS engine?

Comment: And really interesting: why it's so good not to have a sync implmentation of the require() function? why do i want async here?

Comment: @LINQ2Vodka - The reason that so much stuff in the browser is async has to do with the fact that your JavaScript is running in the browser's UI thread. This means that if your thread pauses - for instance, to load a dependency - the browser itself grinds to a bloody halt. That's a horrible experience, and browser makers would get blamed for your shoddy code. So they require that you do everything asynchronously. You'll get used to it: it really is a good habit to get into.